# How do you select all strings in between certain substrings in python and create a csv out of the results?

Tags: python, json, regex, csv, python-requests

I'm trying to parse the results of an API call in python.

```
{'data': [{'type': 'infra_process_running', 'name': 'Custom Plugin Alert - Stopped Running', 'enabled': True, 'filter': {'and': [{'is': {'entityName': 'SOMEHOSTNAME','SOMEHOSTNAME'}}]}, 'id': 123456, 'created_at_epoch_millis': 1513024072143, 'updated_at_epoch_millis': 1513024072176, 'policy_id': 127350, 'comparison': 'below', 'critical_threshold': {'value': 2, 'duration_minutes': 5}, 'process_filter': {'and': [{'is': {'commandLine': 'java'}}]}}], 'meta': {'limit': 50, 'offset': 0, 'total': 1}, 'links': {}}
```

EDIT: Sorry forgot to say this is output from running print on a request in python which is why it's single quoted and not double like JSON

I would like to extract all 'name' and all 'entityName' from this request.
I've tried using regex to search for and store those in a list

```
list.append(re.search(r"', 'name': '(.*?)', '", stringInfJSON))
list.append(re.search(r"{'entityName': ['(.*?)']", stringInfJSON))
```

I would like to extract all 'name' and all 'entityName' from this request.

I would then like to insert all those to an excel spreadsheet in the following format

```
+---------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Somehostname(s)                       | Somehostname2       |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Custom Plugin Alert - Stopped Running | Blah Blah Blah Blah |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are getting the API response in a JSON format, you should be able to use

```
my_dict = json.load([JSON variable])
for x in my_dict['data']:
     list.append(x['name'])
```

the first line will convert the JSON into a python dict, and then you need to loop over it because the JSON contains an array, each element of which presumably has a `name` value. You will need to `import json` in the python file.

I don't recommend you try to use regex for this; there's no reason to convert the JSON response into a string.

To get the entity name, you can use the same method:

```
for x in my_dict['data']:
      for y in x['filter']['and']:
             list.append(y['is']['entityName']
```